# How to print in range?

Tags: python

how would I print something like that in python?

[image]

This is what I could do until now:

```
for i in range(24):
    print("("+str(i)+", "+str(i)+"):",i, end="")
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear what you're actually looking for.  Could you please elaborate on what you actually want here?

Comment: I want to print what's on the picture above, but don't know how to multiply "i" to make it 0,0 125,0 250,0 and so on...

Comment: I dont know if it's because I don't have my maths pants on, but what the f##K is meant to be happening inside the brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
i = 0
for y in range(0, 500, 125):
   for x in range(0, 750, 125):
      print('(%3d, %3d): %3d    ' % (x, y, i), end='')
      i += 1
   print()
```

produces

```
(  0,   0):   0     (125,   0):   1     (250,   0):   2     (375,   0):   3     (500,   0):   4     (625,   0):   5    
(  0, 125):   6     (125, 125):   7     (250, 125):   8     (375, 125):   9     (500, 125):  10     (625, 125):  11    
(  0, 250):  12     (125, 250):  13     (250, 250):  14     (375, 250):  15     (500, 250):  16     (625, 250):  17    
(  0, 375):  18     (125, 375):  19     (250, 375):  20     (375, 375):  21     (500, 375):  22     (625, 375):  23
```

Alternatively, with a single loop:

```py
for i in range(24):
   print('(%3d, %3d): %3d    ' % (i % 6 * 125, i // 6 * 125, i), end='')
   if (i + 1) % 6 == 0:
      print()
```

Comment: OP appears to be using python3.x, you might want to convert your print statement to a function accordingly.

Comment: @mgilson: Good point, thanks.

Comment: What does %3d represent?

Comment: @user1824179 -- It means write an integer which takes up 3 spaces.  `1` is written as `"  1"`

Comment: @NPE -- normally I don't pick on things like that, but the trailing comma to suppress a newline in python2.x always seemed like a funky syntax and it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import count
counter = count()
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(6):
        print ((j*125,i*125),':',next(counter),end='\t')
    print()
```

You can use string formatting to get the alignment of text that you want.